# Is it possible to create synthetic non-paired quantum fluctuations to create particles out of quantum foam and if so, how?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics

I had an idea to create a device that would use very powerful lasers with magnetic controllers in a quantum vacuum to create particles from high energy states or "blips" in quantum fields and also I am only in middle school so I hope this shows that most kids are idiots (don't get me started on bullies) but some are actually smart

Comment: Sorry Peter, but because of your age you need to get a parent or guardian to use Stack Exchange on your behalf. Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61770/334566

Comment: @Peter Barendt : Also I'd advise you read, accept and _save_ my answer (if you really like it) and then close this Q. & follow PM 2Ring's suggestion to avoid possible troubles :)

Comment: Peter if you want to work with physics try the MIT oven courses in physics https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/

Answer (score 2):

(Don't worry: no not all kids are "dumb"; I was interested in this stuff too at that time but the Internet and other resources were not as well-developed as they were now. I really wish I could re-do life over again but with my birthdate shifted forward 10 or more years ... sigh, c'est la vie. That said I was called stupid a ton for asking questions in a socially awkward manner on the more primitive forum sites than this that were available and getting responses to "go to a university library" and then having to tell them that I lacked the financial means to get to one. I completely skipped that whole "skewwl" thing but managed to find ways to get "*adults*" to be my *bullies* [hence the scare quotes] to too much detrimental effect...)

---

Your idea is actually not that wrong, but the *justification* for it is. I believe you have been reading a lot of "pop science" expositions of quantum theory given your idea of "particles 'blipping'" or "quantum fluctuations" in and out of the vacuum. This isn't really a good way to conceptualize a quantum field vacuum: instead, what "really" happens is that *any agent who can only sense a finite area of the vacuum (as any real one will be limited to) will always sense the presence of particles therein*, but those particles are as much a product of the agent's act of sensing as they are of the vacuum itself. A lot of complicated maths goes into this that I have not fully explored personally, either. Hence, this itself is not quite the right justification for this.

But what *also* is true is that while this *naive pop-sci picture* is wrong, your idea that a suitably-powerful laser would create particles out of its beam *is*, at least in theory, correct: it is called the "*Schwinger effect*". To understand why this is requires a little bit deeper a dive into quantum electrodynamic theory and relativistic quantum field theories (RQFTs) in general.

You may have heard of something called "wave-particle duality"; and what I will say is this is also another admittedly poor concept - the "proper" one is *particle-field duality*: to any type of particle you can think of, there is a corresponding quantum field - a sense in which that, associated with the given *type* of particle, there is a type of "value" that can be measured at each and every point in all of space - and conversely, to each such value-object it could be considered just as much as a swarm of those particles. For lasers, the particles are photons and the values are the electric and magnetic fields (e.g. how many V/m and Teslas at each point). Likewise, there is also such a field for *electrons*. And that's where it gets more interesting.

You see, because of this duality, we can thus talk about a suitably-strong distortion of such a field over a region of space just as much as being the manifestation of particles within that area, and when there are particles present, the field values are (modulo a bunch of subtler caveats) large. And then, because these fields interact with each other, any input of energy into one will show up as an effect on the other. Moreover, as that input gets stronger, the effect of interaction gets stronger, producing a worse and worse distortion of the other field.

Hence, if you *put enough energy into the electromagnetic field* - i.e. you have a *lot* of photons there - it will exert so much influence on the *electron* field that you will distort it enough to *cause veritably whole new electrons* (as well as their anti-matter counterparts, *positrons*) to appear!

That said, if you want to do this, you're going to need to likely get your Ph.D. in experimental physics and will heap some fame on your name if it doesn't happen before then because testing the Schwinger effect experimentally with a laser is an area of active research right now. And if you want to see the kind of lasers you'll need:

https://eli-laser.eu/

---

P.S. and important "Life Pro Tip" regarding all that Ph.D. business, I feel I should share given my personal history: because you and I contact at these stages in life (and no other reason), make sure to spend 4 years from here maximizing your academic ability so you can qualify to get into a *quality* college ideally at ages 16-18 and not end up waste more of your time at a poor one due to not being able to satisfy the admissions monsters, by the way, because of lack of *prior*, *wise* use of your young years. May not need Harvard or MIT, but at least aim for the equivalent of Boston University or higher (not sure what country you're from; but that's the top 40, I believe, in USA). You need that *discipline* - hope you've learned it already, if not, time to get going and consider yourself LUCKY to have encountered positive inspiration right now at this point in your life!!! :) A quality college, while it helps with learning I find though the much more important factor is *WHO* it gets you in contact with and *WHERE* it puts you *geographically*, than so much *WHAT* it teaches (esp. as if you have enough brains, discipline and/or strategy you can teach yourself) and conversely, the *failure* to attend one leads to further wastage of time in building those extremely vital *connections*. The real scarce resource is *people* more than it is *learning materials.*

Also, I'd advise gently against developing too much egotism: you will someday be an adult (7-10 years from now is the very beginning) and another lesson I want to share with you is to treat others better than they treated you and not to develop a like for vengeance or pride as antidotes. Arrogant adults and bullies likely become that way by such. It's a cycle; break the cycle.

Comment: Well for the particle-field duality, there is really only the quantum field. The particle is just the vibration of that field. For wave-particle duality there is really only the wave.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get new particles providing the energy with lasers, there has to be an interaction/scattering  of the photons that compose the laser light with some electric or magnetic field. The "vacuum foam" and (virtual particles in general )is just a mathematical formulation of the way these  interactions can happen. Because of energy and momentum conservation , they cannot happen by a photon interacting with  just the vacuum loops. There has to be a field to balance the energy and momentum conservation.

[Pair production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production#Cross_section) can happen in the field of a nucleus, the energy  momentum balance happening with the electric field of the nucleus and finally with the nucleus itself . Because of quantum number conservation the particles have to be particle-antiparticle pairs.

[image: pairprod]

The γ here is a [virtual particle](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html), i.e. its invariant mass is not zero but depends on the kinematics of the interaction.

There are plans of making [colliders with laser beams](https://www.slac.stanford.edu/pubs/beamline/26/1/26-1-kim.pdf), that will generate particles by their photons colliding with each other and creating real particles to be studied in experiments.